# Проблемы со списком css,html

Tags: html, css

Возникла такая проблема: 
Необходимо реализовать вот такую конструкцию, как ниже на скриншоте. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался реализовать ul, но как-то не выходит.

```css
  .li_custom_markk p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
}

.lipluspadd {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  padding-left: 13px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ul_custom_mark {
  width: 430px;
  height: 327px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 27px;
}

.ul_custom_markkk {
  width: 430px;
  height: 327px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 27px;
}

.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks {
  background: url("../img/icons/2-layers2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks {
  background: url("../img/icons/2-layers3.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks {
  background: url("../img/icons/2-layers4.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks {
  background: url("../img/icons/2-layers4.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks+.li_custom_marks {
  background: url("../img/icons/5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk {
  background: url("../img/icons/7.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk {
  background: url("../img/icons/8.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk {
  background: url("../img/icons/9.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk+.li_custom_markk {
  background: url("../img/icons/10.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

.li_custom_marks p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
  <ul class="ul_custom_mark">
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_marks">
        <p>Внедрение и сопровождение</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_marks">
        <p>Отпимизация под ваши нужды</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_marks">
        <p>Разработка уникальных конфигураций</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_marks">
        <p>Удалённое сопровождение и обслуживание баз данных</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_marks">
        <p>Интеграция 1С с другими программами и базами данных</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
  <ul class="ul_custom_markkk">
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_markk">
        <p>Восстановление баз данных и исправление ошибок</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_markk">
        <p>Интеграция 1С с оборудованием </p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_markk">
        <p>Консультации по работе 1С</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_markk">
        <p>Ускорение процессов формирования отчетов, обработок данных</p>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="lipluspadd">
      <li class="li_custom_markk">
        <p>Внедрение типовых и собственных конфигураций</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Подогнать все по итогу не получается, при установления одной высоты для li, не могу центрировать все по центру, т.к. где-то 2-х строчный текст, где-то 3-х. Уже готов все удалять и заново, но может кто-нибудь может подсказать, как лучше это реализовать? Заранее большое спасибо. Код ужасен, знаю, но уже столько всего перепробовал, что получилась вот такая каша.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для одинаковой высоты левой и правой колонки я бы использовал `flexbox`:

```css
.custom_line{
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.custom_mark:first-child{
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.custom_mark:last-child{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.col-md-5{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
}

p{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_line">
  <div class="custom_mark col-md-5">
    <p>Внедрение и сопровождение</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom_mark col-md-5">
    <p>Восстановление баз данных и исправление ошибок</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="custom_line">
  <div class="custom_mark col-md-5">
    <p>Внедрение и сопровождение</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom_mark col-md-5">
    <p>Восстановление баз данных и исправление ошибок</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Разбивать надо на строчки и колонки внутри, а не наоборот.

upd: выровнял текст по вертикали

Answer (score 2):

```css
.block {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

li {
  width: inherit;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего эту задачу решить через `column-count: 2`. Вот примерное решение:

```css
.item-list{
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 16.66667%;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: ulcounter;
}
.item-list li{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.item-list li:before{
    counter-increment: ulcounter;
    content: counter(ulcounter);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
.item-list li p {
    margin: 0;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.li_custom_marks p {
    margin: 0;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="item-list">
    <li>
        <p>Внедрение и сопровождение</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Отпимизация под ваши нужды</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Разработка уникальных конфигураций</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Удалённое сопровождение и обслуживание баз данных</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Интеграция 1С с другими программами и базами данных</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Восстановление баз данных и исправление ошибок</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Интеграция 1С с оборудованием </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Консультации по работе 1С</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Ускорение процессов формирования отчетов, обработок данных</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Внедрение типовых и собственных конфигураций</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

свойство `order` можно скриптом расставить

```css
*,:before,:after{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ol{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset:list;
  max-width:400px;
  line-height:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
ol li{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  border:1px solid;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0 0 10px;
  width:calc(50% - 15px);
}
ol li:before{
  counter-increment:list;
  content:counter(list);
  display:inline-block;
  width:1.5em;
  height:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:1.5;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  margin-right:7px;
}
ol>li:nth-child(1){order:1}
ol>li:nth-child(2){order:3}
ol>li:nth-child(3){order:5}
ol>li:nth-child(4){order:7}
ol>li:nth-child(5){order:9}
ol>li:nth-child(6){order:2}
ol>li:nth-child(7){order:4}
ol>li:nth-child(8){order:6}
ol>li:nth-child(9){order:8}
ol>li:nth-child(10){order:10}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>dasd asd asda sda das </li>
  <li>as dasd asd asd asd </li>
  <li>as dasa a sd asd asdasda g</li>
  <li>asdas das asd asdas dasda </li>
  <li>sad asd asdasf fdsfdsfsd </li>
  <li>dasd asd asda sda das asda sd asd asd</li>
  <li>as dasd asd asd asd </li>
  <li>as dasa a sd asd asdasda g</li>
  <li>asdas das asd asdas dasda </li>
  <li>sad asd asdasf fdsfdsfsd </li>
</ol>
```